# Using Apple Pay in a dynamically rendered iframe (same-origin)

Tags: javascript, iframe, applepay

I'm trying to use Apple Pay within an iframe that I create and populate its DOM with Javascript.

(Context: I work on 3rd party widget that websites can embed into their existing websites, hence the need to isolate everything in an iframe; there are other options for isolating, but this is what we currently use).

Apple Pay has two requirements, as far as I know:

1. The frame has a secure source
2. The frame has the same origin as the main frame on the page.

In order to satisfy these two requirements, I have tried to use the following code (tested in Safari):

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
// the iframe origin is 'about:blank'
// let's try to fix that
iframe.contentDocument.open()
// Render the DOM content here
iframe.contentDocument.close()
// That seems to set the origin of the iframe to the origin of the caller of `open`

// Test 
const script = iframe.contentDocument.createElement('script')
script.text = `
console.log(location.origin == parent.location.origin)
// true, so iframe origin should be secure now like the parent

console.log(ApplePaySession.supportsVersion(2))
// But it still triggers the following error:
// "InvalidAccessError: Trying to start an Apple Pay session from an insecure document."
`
iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(script)
```

As you can see, this does not work despite the fact that the document origin is recognized as being the same as the parent origin and it is secure.

In conclusion: Is there any way I can use Apple Pay from within an iframe which I dynamically create on a 3rd party website?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Looking into the same issue. I know that Safari 17.0 now allows you to add `allow="payment"` to your iframe to bypass the cross-origin errors. There is still an issue on merchantValidation where the payment is not complete and cancels your session though.

Comment: My solution was to start the Apple Pay session outside the iframe

Comment: It seems that this won't be solved with Safari 17 since, the issue here is that Apple considers an iframe with `src="about:blank` not "secure".
See the WebKit source code: https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/8afe31a018b11741abdf9b4d5bb973d7c1d9ff05/Source/WebCore/Modules/applepay/PaymentSession.cpp#L39

Comment: @ShayaUlman How were you able to start the AP session outside the iframe? Do you own both websites or include it in a script? Any example would be very helpful!

Comment: The iframe we have is a same-origin iframe, meaning, it doesn't have a `src` that points to a different url, the src is `about:blank`, so we do have access to the outside